# How can I connect to SFTP service based on Azure Storage Account Solution with BizTalk 2013

Tags: azure, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a requirement to connect to an SFTP service based on Azure Storage Account Solution, I setted my receive location as following : [image: RL parameters]

But the receive location stay disabled. I was able to connect with WinSCP and see the folder where I am supposed to pick up files so connection parameters are good.

How can I connect to this kind of service from BizTalk 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With earlier version of BizTalk it doesn't use WinSCP and there is a limited set of SSH Cyphers that it supports.

When it tries to connect to an SFTP server that has a set of cypher that doesn't have a match for the one that the BizTalk SFTP adapter supports, then it will throw a very unhelpful error in the Windows Application Events.

> Details:"Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.SftpInvoker.SftpException: Open SFTP connection error.

To resolve this you have the following options

- Upgrade to BizTalk 2020 which does use the WinSCP DLL, and also make sure you apply the latest CU, which will also mean that it supports a later version of the WinSCP library.
- Use a third party SFTP adapter such as nSoftware

I've use the nSoftware adapter successfully in BizTalk 2013 R2 to connect to an SFTP server that the native SFTP adapter could not connect with.

See my blog [BizTalk SFTP – Open SFTP connection error](https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2018/10/03/biztalk-sftp-open-sftp-connection-error/)